# How can I get each url for each tab. www.mysite/pages/#tabid?

Tags: wordpress, url, tabs

Here is my website: http://jiabaoyuezi.com/%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1/

And there are 5 tabs on this page with 5 different tab ID.

How can I come up with 5 url link?

should I get my link with my current url + /#tabid

Please help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The full url for each tab has the followning format:

```
http://yourdomain.com/pagename/tabid
```

If it is a post then it has a slighty different format. You can see the format of your pages and post at Settings -> Permalinks .